# Can't reference public folder from node.js deployment with firebase

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions, firebase-hosting

After watching [Node.js apps on Firebase Hosting](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LOeioOKUKI8) I tried to create a project with Polymer and NodeJs/express and firebase hosting.
In the linked Video it is shown that firebase would serve by default the static public/index.html file which is why they remove it to then serve a dynamic one. However, this particular file is in the same functions directory and not anymore placed in the public folder.
Does this mean that my whole project should be placed in the functions folder or just the app entry-point? I am not able to send a file that is placed in my public folder as shown below.

- project

  - functions

    - server.js
  - public

    - index.html

```
app.get('*', (req, res) => {
   res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, '/public/index.html'));
})
```

I believe firebase is hosting the public and the function folder differently or am I referencing just wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You'll need to nest your `public` folder *inside* the `functions` folder to be able to reference files from it in your functions. You can do this just by changing the `public` setting in `firebase.json` to be e.g. `functions/public` and then moving the directory inside `functions`.

You would then be able to do something like you're describing.

Comment: Alright, thats what I thought. I just wasn't sure if this is the right way or if I am missing something. One thing I do not get though, at the end of the video he is linking a stylesheet from the public folder to the index that is placed in the functions folder because he wants to keep static assets separat

Comment: In general you shouldn't use Cloud Functions to duplicate capabilities that Firebase Hosting offers natively. So if you're just looking to serve `index.html` from all paths, you should use a [rewrite](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/url-redirects-rewrites#section-rewrites) instead.

Comment: I previously had functions + public split as per the tutorial - I then had a file containing routes inside functions where I was calling res.render(). In some cases it would correctly find my style.css inside public, and other times it would try and pull style.css from the same dir as the route was in. Why would it work in some cases and not in others? (Should this be a separate question?) Thanks in advance!

Comment: Sorry to be annoying - I went ahead and asked a similar question if you're interested. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47966496/problems-rendering-view-with-node-js-and-firebase-functions.

Answer (score -1):

I think no need to move entire public folder into functions folder. You can use the relative path like this

```
app.get('*', (req, res) => {
     res.sendFile( './../public/index.html'));
})
```

It worked for me... try this.

Comment: This only works if you're serving locally. Once deployed, it doesn't.